# Android: RemoveAllItems from view doesn't refresh size

Tags: android, scrollview, xamarin.android, android-linearlayout

I have a `ScrollView` that contains a `LinearLayout`.

In code I add items to the `LinearLayout` and it nicely expands.

When I remove, in code, all the items from the `LinearLayout`, the `LinearLayout` stays the same size, it's empty though.

How do I get the `ScrollView` to `reclaim the height` that the `LinearLayout` used when it had items and shrink back the LinearLayout to use the least height as it is now empty?

I have tried (in C#):

```
        linearLayout.RemoveAllViewsInLayout();
        linearLayout.PostInvalidate();
        scrollView.PostInvalidate();
```

Java or C# answers are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only have Java experience with Android, so I would try using:

```
linearLayout.requestLayout();
```

This should cause another layout pass, and assuming your `LinearLayout` is set to `WRAP_CONTENT` it will measure all the children and size itself to fit the smallest space that the children occupy (or `minHeight` if you have that set and it is larger).

Answer (score 0):

This trick seems to work. The result is that the linearlayout ids resized and the scrollview as well:

```
        linearLayout.RemoveAllViewsInLayout();
        linearLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        scrollView.SmoothScrollTo(0, 0);
        linearLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
```

There must be a better way, but this works.